# Problem with protractor peer dependencies when installing any package in Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm

When I want to install any new package, the following errors will be printed in the console :
(this time I wanted to add ngx-bootstrap by executing: `ng add ngx-bootstrap`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.0
npm ERR! Found: protractor@6.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/protractor
npm ERR!   dev protractor@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional protractor@"^7.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: protractor@7.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/protractor
npm ERR!   peerOptional protractor@"^7.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Although running npm commands with --legacy-peer-deps will solve the problems in some cases (not for ngx-bootstrap) but I want to know the reason for this problem and solve it once forever

This is package.json :

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.3",
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngmodule/material-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.0.1",
    "@thisissoon/angular-inviewport": "^4.2.2",
    "@thisissoon/angular-scrollspy": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.32",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^11.1.0",
    "angular-notifier": "^9.1.0",
    "angular-responsive-carousel": "^2.0.2",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "ng-scroll-spy": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-spy": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^15.0.1",
    "ngx-countdown": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-horizontal-scroll-menu": "^1.0.11",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-simple-countdown": "^1.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.5",
    "swiper": "^7.3.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.1.1",
    "@ngbmodule/material-carousel": "^0.7.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.4"
  }
}
```

Edit: After changing protector from 6.0.0 to 7.0.0 other conflicts were created :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=6.1.0" from @angular-slider/ngx-slider@2.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-slider/ngx-slider
npm ERR!     @angular-slider/ngx-slider@"^2.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0-0" from @angular/cdk@13.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"13.1.1" from @angular/material@13.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@">=12.0.0" from @swimlane/ngx-charts@20.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-charts
npm ERR!       @swimlane/ngx-charts@"^20.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!   13 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!   @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^11.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@9.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
npm ERR!     @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"^9.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have protractor `^7.0.0` used Angular 13 requires it (peer dependency). Meanwhile you are using version 6.

change

```
   "protractor": "^6.0.0",
```

to

```
   "protractor": "^7.0.0",
```

and run install, then retry your operation.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss and thanks for the reply. I changed the protector to version 7 but other conflicts were made. I changed the post and add the new logs to it

Comment: And you just have to resolve those as well.

Comment: well I dont know how to solve the conflicts, I mean how to find which version of each peer dependency to use!

Comment: Read the error messages. It says that X package requires Y but you have Z in your project. Take look into the first case with protractor and try to figure out why I have pointed out that lack of protractor 7.0.0 is the issue - yes, I have just read the message. I didnt "remember" ther requirements of each ag version (duh)